# How to understand auction winner (Prebid/Apstag/Adx)

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

On my site, I use Prebid and Apstag.
How can I understand who won the auction?
Is there a way to decrypt the CPM sent by Amazon? 
How to clearly understand who won Prebid / Amazon or Adx?
I am trying to use this method

```
        pbjs.onEvent('bidWon', function(data) {
          console.log(data.bidderCode+ ' won the ad server auction for ad unit ' +data.adUnitCode+ ' at ' +data.cpm+ ' CPM');
        });
```

, but if I get a won bid, Chrome extension [Adwizard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adwizard/kndnhcfdajkaickocacghchhpieogbjh?hl=en) tells that 'Prebid Won: No'.

thank you in advance

Comment: Using the code mentioned in this link(http://prebid.org/dev-docs/troubleshooting-tips.html) you can get all the bids received and which all won.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to see who won would be to check your DFP/GAM, since they are determining the final winner based on the Line Item that serves from both Prebid and Amazon UAM.

A non programmatic way to do this would be to use the Google debug tool on your page. Append your url with "&googfc" or type this in console "googletag.openConsole()". From there you'll see your ad units, you can click delivery diagnostics, and it will open a window in your DFP/GAM and you can see what Line Item won.

A programmatic way would be setup an on [SlotRenderEndedEvent](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.events.slotrenderendedevent) listener with DFP. You can then log the line item and advertiser which will give you the bid price.